# How to use register_printf_specifier with printf_size?

Tags: c, g++, printf, deprecated, glibc

I was using glibc's `register_printf_function` with predefined library handlers `printf_size` and `printf_size_info` like this:

```
register_printf_function('B', printf_size, printf_size_info);
register_printf_function('b', printf_size, printf_size_info);
```

But now `register_printf_function`is deprecated, so I decided to use `register_printf_specifier` (that has the same parameters) instead of it, but faced another issue:

> ```
> app_setup.c:1981: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(
>     const printf_info *, size_t, int *)throw ()’ to ‘int (*)(
>     const printf_info *, size_t, int *, int *)’ app_setup.c:1981: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int
> register_printf_specifier(
>     int, int (*)(FILE *, const printf_info *, const void * const *), int
>     (*)(const printf_info *, size_t, int *, int *))’ app_setup.c:1982: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(
>     const printf_info *, size_t, int *)throw ()’ to ‘int (*)(
>     const printf_info *, size_t, int *, int *)’ app_setup.c:1982: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int
> register_printf_specifier(
>     int, int (*)(FILE *, const printf_info *, const void * const *), int
>     (*)(const printf_info *, size_t, int *, int *))’ make[1]: *** [app_setup.o] Error 1
> ```

**What is wrong with these `register_printf_specificator` calls? Is it possible to use predefined handlers with this function?**

**Is there a correct way to use predefined handlers without calling `register_printf_function`?**

Comment: `that has the same parameters` - Apparently it doesn't. There's an extra `int *`.

Comment: @cremno Here's the declarations of both functions from `printf.h`:
`extern int register_printf_function (int __spec, printf_function __func,
                                     printf_arginfo_function __arginfo)
  __THROW __attribute_deprecated__;`


`extern int register_printf_specifier (int __spec, printf_function __func,
                                      printf_arginfo_size_function __arginfo)
  __THROW;`

Comment: Take a closer look: it's `printf_arginfo_function` vs. `printf_arginfo_size_function`. So adjust your function and find out what the *new* 4th parameter does or if it can be ignored.